# An ImportError occurs when importing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror, pypy

I install matplotlib in pypy by downloading the wheel in [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) and its name is `matplotlib‑3.4.2‑pp37‑pypy37_pp73‑win_amd64.whl`.

My pypy version is
`Python 3.7.10 (51efa818fd9b, Apr 04 2021, 12:09:32) [PyPy 7.3.4 with MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]` on win32.

But when I import matplolib something wrong happened.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Bitao_Dai\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\Bitao_Dai\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, _c_internal_utils
ImportError: cannot import name '_c_internal_utils'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something went wrong during installation, a file was either not installed or was corrupted, I got the same error sometime back.
The following solution worked for me:
Go to cmd.exe, workon your venv(if you're using one), else type:

```
(venv) C:>pip uninstall matplotlib
Found existing installation: matplotlib 3.4.2
Uninstalling matplotlib-3.4.2:
 Would remove:
  c:\matplotlib-3.4.2-py3.9-nspkg.pth
  c:\matplotlib-3.4.2.dist-info\*
  c:\site-packages\matplotlib\*
  c:\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\*
  c:\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\*
  c:\mpl_toolkits\axisartist\*
  c:\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\*
  c:\mpl_toolkits\tests\*
  c:\pylab.py
Proceed (y/n)? y
 Successfully uninstalled matplotlib-3.4.2
```

After this:
(venv) C:>pip install matplotlib

This should work. Hope this helped. In my experience, it is the best practice to install packages using pip.

When I run pypy3 -m pip install matplotlib ,there are some troubles happened

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\Bitao_Dai\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\pypy3.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\BITAO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xzb8mrhq\matplotlib_c20db475c8ba4ee6bec5b5683911048a\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\BITAO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xzb8mrhq\matplotlib_c20db475c8ba4ee6bec5b5683911048a\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\BITAO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-narl5jt6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Bitao_Dai\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\include\matplotlib'
cwd: C:\Users\BITAO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xzb8mrhq\matplotlib_c20db475c8ba4ee6bec5b5683911048a
Complete output (552 lines):

```
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.
```

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Bitao_Dai\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\pypy3.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\BITAO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xzb8mrhq\matplotlib_c20db475c8ba4ee6bec5b5683911048a\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\BITAO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xzb8mrhq\matplotlib_c20db475c8ba4ee6bec5b5683911048a\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\BITAO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-narl5jt6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Bitao_Dai\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\include\matplotlib' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your comment. In fact , I am using pypy, a special python. When I run pypy3 -m pip install matplotlib ,there are some troubles happened

Comment: OK, looks like matplotlib isn't supported by pypy, see [link](http://packages.pypy.org/##matplotlib) for supported packages. All I could find is that version 2.2 could work, have your tried this:
pypy3 -m pip install matplotlib
or 
pypy3 -m pip install matplotlib==2.2

Comment: This page is old and outdated.